# Woocommerce Filter to update tax_class

Tags: wordpress, filter, woocommerce

This filter work well.

```
<pre><code>
    function wc_diff_taxes_for_ajax( $tax_class, $product ) {
        $tax_class = 'Zero Product';
        return $tax_class;
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tax_class', 'wc_diff_taxes_for_ajax', 1, 2 );
</code></pre>
```

I try to fire filter inside my other function but always have an error...
The Ajax part call well and get response. So i don't put it here.

```
<pre><code>
    function manage_taxes_aliquota() {
        if(isset($_POST['tax_class'])) {
            <--What i PUT HERE TO FIRE THE FILTER AND PASS NEW $tax_class-->
        }
       echo 'ok';
       exit;
     } 
     add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_manage-taxes-aliquota', 'manage_taxes_aliquota');
     add_action('wp_ajax_manage-taxes-aliquota', 'manage_taxes_aliquota');
</code></pre>
```

Regards.